# Is there a way to disable CloudFlare DevMode on uploading to server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cloudflare

I would like to know if there's a way to disable CloudFlare Developer Mode every time I upload new files to my server via FTP. 
I know CloudFlare has an API for the DevMode but I'm not familiar with using APi's : https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-settings-change-development-mode-setting
Is there maybe a way to do it with the .htaccess file or a JS pr php solution?
Maybe sounds confusing but would appreciate any help!

Comment: The best (really only, I think) way would be to use the API. I would think you'd want to write a little PHP application on your server that watches for file changes and calls the API when files are changed.

Comment: At first glance, I don't think there is a reason for this method. Uploading a 'new' file means it's not in CF's cache yet. So you wouldn't need dev mode on in the first place.Can you give a use case so we can understand the intention better?

Comment: CF caches the CSS for example, do everytime i make changes to a CSS file, it won't show until I enable Devmode so it purges the cache. Of course this is just a method for convenience I'm asking for but would be interesting to find out